# References for photo-absorption on a nucleus

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, spectroscopy, absorption

I have spent lots of time looking for at least one good reference for nuclear photo-absorption, but it seems like most of the authors I ran into prefer not to make fundamental references. Does anybody knows a good text-book or at least review paper (only theory is of interest) on this subject? Thank you sooooo much in advance!!!